# OAuthException on Facebook Graph API Logout, Works After Refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am using a modified version php-sdk version 3.0.0 sample code at github.com/facebook within the CodeIgniter framework as a helper.

My problem is just as the title says:  When I click the logout anchor (provided by `$Facebook->getLogoutUrl()`) I am redirected back to the same page and receive an OAuthException:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out. thrown in [...]/base_facebook.php on line 959
```

When I refresh, it loads the "login" anchor like it normally would. What is happening on that refresh/post-back that isn't happening on that initial redirect?

I realize this is limited information but due to the problem I think it may be a simple fix.

**EDIT:** This post seems to be relevant: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=71219

Specifically this line:

```
setcookie('fbs_'.$facebook->getAppId(), '', time()-100, '/', '.domain.com');
```

However, I am not sure how to implement this and still use `$facebook->getLogoutUrl();`.

Thanks in advance and just let me know if more information is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem and nearly pulling my hair out.  However, after some research, it appears the problem is an offending cookie.  This line on logout should fix it:

`setcookie('fbs_'.$facebook->getAppId(), '', time()-100, '/', '.domain.com');`

Ensure to add the '.' before the domain name if subdomains are being used.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yea I ran across that in the Facebook developers forums as well.  Source: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=273884#p273884

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, I tried:

`setcookie('fbs_'.$facebook->getAppId(), '', time()-100, '/', '.domain.com');`

This didn't work. What I did, was to just copy from the fb example code:

```
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

The middle part, with if try get user_profile, is a test to get the user profile, and if it fails the userid will be unset. This will make the last part with getLoginUrl() and getLogoutUrl() correct.

I do believe setting the cookie is more correct, than to try a request and see if it fails... but since the setcookie didn't work, I didn't have a choice :(

Stupid facebook that returns a token with this `$user = $facebook->getUser();`, when the user actually is logged out.

Hope this helps those who is in need.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your error it would appear your website is still trying to connect to Facebook using the SDK. When you run the logout function provided by Facebook make sure to clear whatever sessions or storage you have that triggers calls to Facebook.

It's likely that they aren't being cleared before you attempt your Facebook logout, and this is why it still thinks you have a connection but then works fine on refresh.

Comment: That appears to be the issue.  I was hoping there was an easier way to handle it than to craft my own logout url (although that isn't too difficult).  Why would the session not be cleared on a redirect from facebook.com to my domain, but it would on a refresh?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was this:

1. `$facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => site_url('logout')));`
2. Then in the 'logout' controller:
   `$_SESSION = array();`
   `$this->load->view('myoriginalview');`

On logout, the facebook logout url's query string redirect_uri value is set to redirect to the 'logout' controller which then clears the session and loads the view on which the logout button existed in the first place.  Everything functions fine.  Now I just have to figure out how to handle an expired session as opposed to a logged out user -_-

**EDIT:**
What I've done now is invalidate the cookie in the proper manner as described on the facebook developers forum.  I really wish their documentation was better and described this for their PHP SDK.